# Is it safe to modify file in place when replacement is same size as original

Tags: c, mmap

I want to do something similar to `sed -i 's/abc/def/' file` 
but without temp file. In my case match and replacement are of *same* length; is the following safe:

```
fd = open(file, O_RDWR);
fstat(fd, &sbuf);
mm = mmap(0, sbuf.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
i = 0;
while (i < sbuf.st_size) {
   memcpy(tmpbuf, mm + i, BUFSIZ);  // read from mem to tmpbuf (BUFSIZ at a time)
   if ((p = strstr(tmpbuf, needle))) { // match found
     memcpy(mm + i + (p - tmpbuf), replace, strlen(replace)); // strlen(replace) == strlen(needle)
   }
   i += BUFSIZ;
}
munmap(mm, sbuf.st_size);
fsync(fd);
close(fd);
```

(err handling omitted for brevity)

Also, not sure if `mmap` is making this any faster!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "safe". Unlike use of a temp file and atomic `rename` over top of the old file after finishing, there is no atomicity to this operation; other processes could see the file in an intermediate, partially-modified state. And moreover there is not any ordering between the stores; they could see the end of the replacement before they see the beginning of it, or see them in any other conceivable order, and possibly even in *inconsistent* ones if also using `mmap` and not using any memory barriers. Note that there's really nothing special about `mmap`; you could do the same thing with `write` too.

If none of these constitute "unsafety" for you, then the operation is totally safe. In particular it won't truncate the file or anything like that.

Comment: If the host crashes during execution, you could end up with a file with a scattering of partial modifications. So the problem isn't limited to ephemeral view of the file.

Comment: Thanks. I should have been a bit more elaborate. In my case, the file is accessed and written by a single process (not multi-threaded). Should I do a `fsync` after every `memcpy` (the _replace_ operation) ?

Comment: @rici: that's true too, but can happen anyway in the event of a system crash even with atomic renaming, which is only as good as the OS's efforts to harden against data loss on crash (including journaling filesystems, etc.)

Comment: @vyom: It doesn't help order within the individual memcpys.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE: it should not be too hard for the filesystem's atomic rename to guarantee that you end up either with the original or the complete new file, even in the face of a host crash. Of course, if the disk itself is damaged you could end up with neither. But it should protect you from an inconsistent result.